# Joomla 4 WebAssetManager error

Tags: joomla-4.x

I'm a little confused on the documentation for adding assets to my component, and getting an error message:

> There is no "com_supersite.supersite" asset of a "script" type in the registry.

I have a media reference in my manifest file:

```
<media destination="com_supersite" folder="media">
    <file>joomla.assets.json</file>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
</media>
```

My joomla.assets.json file, which I think should register my assets:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "com_supersite",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "Joomla CMS",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "com_supersite.supersite",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_supersite/supersite.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "com_supersite.supersite",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "com_supersite/supersite.css"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then trying to use the script asset in my component view:

```
<?php

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');


/** @var \Joomla\CMS\WebAsset\WebAssetManager $wa */
$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();

$wa->useScript('com_supersite.supersite');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Web_Assets#Register_an_asset), the web asset registry file must be named `joomla.asset.json`, not `joomla.assets.json` to be loaded automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Sharky, my answer worked but it's good to keep with the standards.

Answer (score 2):

@Sharky, you were right to call my original answer incorrect. I wasn't paying enough attention to the names in the asset file compared to the error message received.

I updated the `joomla.asset.xml` file, and now I don't need to register the scripts.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.joomla.org/schemas/json-schema/web_assets.json",
  "name": "com_supersite",
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "description": "Joomla CMS",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "supersite",
      "type": "script",
      "uri": "com_supersite/supersite.js",
      "dependencies": [
        "core",
        "jquery"
      ],
      "attributes": {
        "defer": true
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "supersite",
      "type": "style",
      "uri": "com_supersite/supersite.css"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Component View:**

```
<?php

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');


/** @var CMSApplication $app */
$app = Factory::getApplication();

$wa = $app->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();

$wa->useStyle('supersite')
    ->useScript('supersite');
```

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. If you use a registry file , you don't need to manually register assets in the component.

Comment: @Sharky answer updated, thanks for your help.